# Expected search times with quadratic vs linear probing

Tags: hashing

Why exactly does **quadratic probing** lead to a shorter avg. search time than linear probing?

I fully get that **linear probing** leads to a higher concentration of used slots in the hash table (i.e. higher "**clustering**" of used  consecutive indices). However, it's not immediately trivial (to me at least) **why** that translates into **higher search times** in expectation than in quadratic probing, since in both linear and quadratic probing the first value of the probing sequence determines the rest of the sequence.

I suppose this has to do more with the probability of collisions **between** different probing sequences. Perhaps different auxiliary hash values are less likely to lead to collisions early in the probing sequence in quadratic than in linear hashing, but I haven't seen this result derived or formalized.

Comment: Have you seen analyses of the average search time for both methods?

Comment: I think here it would be very pertinent to consider as well the step-size of the probe. Consider for example, a step size defined as $\max \{i \leq \sqrt{n}: gcd(i,n) = 1$ for linear probing on a table of size $n$. Such a step size would not necessarily lead to obviously being more "clustered" than quadratic probes.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I haven't. If you know of any texts doing it, I'd be highly interested. Thanks.

Comment: @MotiN that's an excellent point. My main reference here is CLRS which discusses these probing designs with a step size of 1, I'd be interested in learning how search times  (successful or not) vary as a function of step size.

Comment: If you assume that the hash function is good, then linear probing is always better than quadratic probing because it has better cache locality.